# Firebase & AngularFire2 'afAuth' does not exist on type 'Appcomponent'

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm currently trying to follow: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

I am getting an issue of:
    Property 'afAuth' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

My app.component.ts looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  constructor(afAuth: AngularFireAuth, db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.user = afAuth.authState;
    this.items = db.list('items');
  }
  login() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
  logout() {
     this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

And my app.module.ts looks like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    databaseURL: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    storageBucket: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  exports: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Anyone know how I would go about fixing this issue? (I am extremely new to programming - just wanting to throw data in to firebase but no tutorials seems to be showing me an up-to-date way on how to go about this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an typescript issue. You haven't set afAuth private or public, so you can only access it inside of the constuctor. Change it like this:

```
...
export class AppComponent {

  ...

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.user = afAuth.authState;
    this.items = db.list('items');
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.This was exactly the issue. I added private before afAuth within my constructor and the issue was fixed.